# How to create a zip of directories -mtime -150

Tags: files, scripting, zip

I want to zip the directories, sub directories, files in main and sub directories from today till 150 days ago.

I only consider the date of the directories where I am running the command, no matter what the date of files and sub directories.

I used the command

```
find . -mtime -151 | xargs  zip tnsd3801_Postfeb16_7106.zip
```

to create the zip of directories. But it is creating the zip of files/sub directories which are only modified between 150 day from today. Could someone help me out.

Comment: Do you have directories within directories (e.g., `dir1/dir17`)?  If `dir1` was modified 140 days ago, but `dir1/dir17` was modified 160 days ago, do you want the contents of `dir17` to be zipped, or just the first-level files in `dir1`?

Comment: I want the dir17 also dir16, dir14 .. file1, file2 .. even though there is no change in them. I want the whole main directory even if a single file update has been done.

Answer (score 1):

The more I read this question, the less sure I am that I understand it. 
I’m going to assume that it is as follows:
You have a directory tree that looks like

```
.
├───dir1             ⋯  Modified 140 days ago.
│   ├───dir11        ⋯  Modified 160 days ago.
│   ├───dir12        ⋯  Modified 140 days ago.
│   ├───dir13        ⋯  (Don’t care.)
│   ├───dir14        ⋯  (Don’t care.)
│   ├───dir15                 .
│   ├───dir16                 .
│   ├───dir17                 .
│   └───  ⋮
└───dir2             ⋯  Modified 160 days ago.
    ├───dir21        ⋯  Modified 140 days ago.
    ├───dir22        ⋯  Modified 160 days ago.
    ├───dir23        ⋯  Modified 140 days ago.
    ├───dir24        ⋯  Modified 160 days ago.
    ├───dir25        ⋯  Modified 140 days ago.
    ├───dir26        ⋯  Modified 160 days ago.
    ├───dir27        ⋯  Modified 140 days ago.
    └───  ⋮
  ⋮
```

… and you want to archive
everything in and under `dir1` (including everything
in and under `dir11`, `dir12`, `dir13`, `dir14`, `dir15`, `dir16`, and `dir17`),
and everything in and under `dir21`, `dir23`, `dir25`, and `dir27`,
but nothing else in or under `dir2`.  (Because you want everything
in and under any directory that’s been modified in the past 150 days.)

You can do this with

```
find . -type d -mtime -151 -prune -print0 | xargs -0 zip -r tnsd3801_Postfeb16_7106.zip
```

- `find . -type d`, obviously,
  finds directories in and under the current directory.
- `find … -mtime -151`, as you know,
  restricts the `find` to objects whose modification date is 150 days ago or less.

  > When I read your question, my first thought was `-mtime -150`. 
  >   Then I saw that you were trying `-mtime -151`,
  >   and I thought, yeah, that makes sense.  Still, you might want to try
  >
  > ```
  > find . -type d -mtime -150 > dirs150
  > find . -type d -mtime -151 > dirs151
  > diff dirs150 dirs151
  > ```
  >
  > to make sure which one you want.
- `find … -prune` says,
  when you find something that meets the criteria specified up to this point,
  *don’t* recurse into this directory,
  but just go on to the next object at this level. 
  So,

  ```
  find . -type d -mtime -151 –prune
  ```

  on the example directory structure that I showed above should report

  ```
  ./dir1
  ./dir2/dir21
  ./dir2/dir23
  ./dir2/dir25
  ./dir2/dir27
  ```

  It doesn’t list `./dir1/dir12`, `./dir1/dir14`, and`./dir1/dir16`,
  because it isn’t searching `./dir1`,
  because it was modified less than 150 days ago.
- Use `-print0` and `xargs -0` to handle directory names
  that might have whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, and newlines)
  in their names.
- Then invoke `zip` with the `-r` option
  to cause it to search the specified directories recursively.

> Note: If you have a ***lot*** of directories, i.e., so many
>   that the list of their names is hundreds of thousands of characters long,
>   `xargs` might need to execute `zip` a few times. 
>   This shouldn’t be a problem, as
>
> ```
> zip myarc file1 file2
> zip myarc file3 file4
> ```
>
> should result in `myarc.zip` containing`file1`, `file2`, `file3`, and `file4`,
>   because `zip` normally *adds* to existing archives,
>   rather than clobbering them and overwriting them. 
>   But note, by the same argument,
>   that you should ensure that `tnsd3801_Postfeb16_7106.zip` does not exist
>   before you issue the above command,
>   unless you want to add to its pre-existing contents.